# npm run watch gives errors after update to Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: macos, npm, macos-mojave

After upgrading the system I get the error as shown below while trying to run npm run watch.

Npm version is 6.4.1
Node v. 11.0.0

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (67)
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? I googled for solutions and find eg. this one https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764 but nothing helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use

```
npm rebuild node-saas --force
```

and that worked for me on Mojave, Node 11.4.0

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution.
It turned out that I had to install newer version of node by executing:

```
sudo n latest
```

At the time I write this the newest version of node is 11.1.0.
When the newest node is installed I could rebuild node-saas by:

```
npm rebuild node-saas
```

it takes a while to compile all of this, but after that all works just fine.

Edit: I just try this solution with other project and rebuilding node-saas didn't want to start. What helped was remove the node_modules category and executing npm install.

Comment: You have a lot of typos in there. But yes, it does work (npm rebuild none-sass). And this problem is not OS-specific. I had it on Sierra after homebrew upgraded my node version.

Comment: John, what are you talking about? What typos mate? And this particular error in this particular case, yes, it is system specific.

Comment: ;)It's node-sass, not node-saas! Be careful with which packages you are installing

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with Node version. the latest Node-Sass supports node version below 9. 
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2

So try downgrading node to lower versions like below

`npm install -g n` <-- will install n, which is used to install the required node version

`n 9` <--  will install node version 9.x.x

now delete node modules and package.json.lock file and `npm install`